# CSS Trapezoid shape with text and borders

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-shapes, shapes

I'm trying to build this: [Category Title Trapezoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24XqJ.png)

I need it to be responsive. Already tried with `borders` (wich are not responsive), `skew`, `rotations`, `:before`, `:after`... with no luck.

I was able to make the trapezoid using before, but without the `3px solid black border`.

Can you please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sow us what you have tried but frankly an SVG would be the simplest method.

Comment: the duplicate give a more complex case but it contain the part you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you can do it on SVG

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 624 55" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M9,10 609,10 609,26 10,45z"  fill="#0894CC" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"/>
  <text x="30" y="33" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; fill: #fff; text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;">destacados</text>
</svg>
```